# Powershell is returning type as string instead of object when running from a function

Tags: powershell

I have a very strange problem when calling ie. Get-PNPFolder

If I run this command directly in the powershell prompt it returns a folder object as expected, so I can work on with that object

```
$folder = Get-PnPFolder -Url $currentFolder
```

If put the same command into a function in a ps1 file or a psm1 file, it returns the type as a string, and the rest of the commands fails..

I tried to use the clientcontext instead but it had the same problem..

I had similar problems with this

```
$addedItem = Add-PnPDocumentSet -List $listInfo.Name -ContentType $ctInfo.Name -Name $item.Name
```

In the prompt I get the full path to the new documentset, but within a script I get nothing.  If I run without the $addedItem =  before, it will write out the full path.. So I guess it is something in the variable assignment

Comment: "*If put the same command into a function in a ps1 file or a psm1 file*", please show a (minimized) version of this `.ps1` file and tell us *how* you invoke it.

Comment: PowerShell tends to have so wacky return semantics and from what I recall extra output during the execution of the function will make the return type *Object[]* instead of the expected object from the return line. An example as @iRon would help to confirm this.

Comment: thanks @iRon I started to make a minimized version and discovered a really dissapointing rookie mistake.. I put the code into a function with 3 parameters, one of them were $Folder. I'm sorry.. Guess I was too tired last night..